# Multidimensional array - duplicate of values through iterations

Tags: php, arrays, magento, multidimensional-array

I have started working with Magento, and I'm trying to get all custom options associated with a given product.
I've found a solution to that, however, I ran into issues.

My PHP-code:

```
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $optionInfo) :
    $values = $optionInfo->getValues(); 

    foreach ($values as $values) :
        $valuesArray[$values['option_type_id']] = array("option_type_id" => $values['option_type_id'], "option_id" => $values['option_id'], "title" => $values['title']);
    endforeach;

    $option = array("id" => $optionInfo->getId(), "type" => $optionInfo->getType(), "title" => $optionInfo->getTitle(), "values" => $valuesArray);
    $options[$optionInfo->getId()]= $option;
endforeach;
```

It sure do return the correct information. Atleast in the first iteration:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [type] => drop_down
        [title] => Custom option 1
        [values] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 4
                        [option_id] => 2
                        [title] => Flaphack 1
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 5
                        [option_id] => 2
                        [title] => Flaphack 2
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 6
                        [option_id] => 2
                        [title] => Flaphack 3
                    )

            )

    )
```

However, during the second iteration (and perhaps even the third and forth and so on), I'm having duplicates of the values. In the second iteration, I'm getting the same values as i got in the first iteration PLUS the correct values for the second iteration:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [type] => drop_down
        [title] => Custom option 2
        [values] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 4
                        [option_id] => 2
                        [title] => Flaphack 1
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 5
                        [option_id] => 2
                        [title] => Flaphack 2
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 6
                        [option_id] => 2
                        [title] => Flaphack 3
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 1
                        [option_id] => 1
                        [title] => Flaphack 1.1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 2
                        [option_id] => 1
                        [title] => Flaphack 1.2
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [option_type_id] => 3
                        [option_id] => 1
                        [title] => Flaphack 1.3
                    )

            )

    )
```

Do you guys have any idea what's going on? Would be greatly appriciated.

Best,
Nikolaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $optionInfo) :
$values = $optionInfo->getValues(); 
$valuesArray = array(); // added line
foreach ($values as $values) :
    $valuesArray[$values['option_type_id']] = array("option_type_id" => $values['option_type_id'], "option_id" => $values['option_id'], "title" => $values['title']);
endforeach;

$option = array("id" => $optionInfo->getId(), "type" => $optionInfo->getType(), "title" =>    $optionInfo->getTitle(), "values" => $valuesArray);
$options[$optionInfo->getId()]= $option;
endforeach;
```

The `$valuesArray` is getting values in each iteration and you never cleared it. So when the outer `foreach` gets into second loop the `$valuesArray` gets values in incremental fashion.  If you clear `$valuesArray` in each iteration of outer `foreach` you will get what you wanted.

Comment: First of all, thanks. It worked. Second: Can you explain to me why the declation of $valuesArray being an array before the foreach sorted the issue??

Comment: Ah, I see. Cheers bud. Unfortunately, I can't do that just yet. In need of more reputation in order to do so. :-/